# Custom UIButton Causes Storyboard Agent Crash Swift

Tags: swift, crash, xcode-storyboard, ibdesignable

I created a custom UIButton class and it causing the storyboard agent to fail. 
I'm Including my extensions cause I really don't know what the problem is. 
I tried to debug this view from the storyboard but it sends me straight to assembly code.
I tried to make it a without @IBDesignable, but it still cause a crash.
Also if you tips for improving how I'm writing my class I'll be glad to hear them.
I'll be glad if you can help me
This is my class:

```
@IBDesignable class customButton: UIButton{

    private let imagesPadding: CGFloat = 2
    private var ArrowSymbleImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBInspectable var iconImageInspectable: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "globe")!{
          willSet {
            if (ArrowSymbleImageView != nil) {
                ArrowSymbleImageView.image = newValue
            }
         }
    }

    @IBInspectable var BackgroundColorInspectable: UIColor = .white {
         willSet {
            self.backgroundColor  = newValue
            if (ArrowSymbleImageView != nil) {
                if (self.BackgroundColorInspectable.isDarkColor) {
                   ArrowSymbleImageView.tintColor = .white
                }else{
                   ArrowSymbleImageView.tintColor = .black
                }
            }
         }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.generalInit()
    }

    private func generalDeinit() {
        ArrowSymbleImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    private func generalInit() {

        self.backgroundColor = self.BackgroundColorInspectable

        self.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft], radius: self.width() / 2 * 0.7)
        self.dropShadow()


        let sizePartFromView: CGFloat = 4
        ArrowSymbleImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.width() / 2 - (self.width() / sizePartFromView / 2),
                                                         y: self.height() / 2 - (self.height() / sizePartFromView / 2),
                                                         width: self.width() / sizePartFromView,
                                                         height: self.height() / sizePartFromView))
        ArrowSymbleImageView.image = self.iconImageInspectable
        if (self.BackgroundColorInspectable.isDarkColor) {
            ArrowSymbleImageView.tintColor = .white
        }else{
            ArrowSymbleImageView.tintColor = .black
        }
        ArrowSymbleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(ArrowSymbleImageView)
    }
}


internal extension UIView {
   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}


internal extension UIView {

    func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: -2, height: 2)) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowOffset = size
    layer.shadowRadius = 1

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
  }

  func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowOffset = offSet
    layer.shadowRadius = radius

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
  }
}

internal extension UIColor
{
    var isDarkColor: Bool {
        var r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        (r, g, b, a) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let lum = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
        return  lum < 0.50 ? true : false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you symbolize the crash? What does the error say in the debug console?

Comment: That's the thing if I run this it works. The crash is only in the storyboard and it doesn't tell why the agent crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this:

```
 UIImage(systemName: "globe")!
```

Is there a reason why you instantiate a custom image this way? Is "globe" an apple provided default image?

You should be really using, if this isn't a default image.

```
UIImage(named:"globe")!
```

Comment: Hi jay, Apple has a set of system symbols you can use in your apps now - and yes "globe" is one of them. Here's a direct link to download the SF Symbols App: https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/SF-Symbols.dmg

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Force unwrapping when you do not have confirmation about data always use optional binding and do change following line in code from this UIImage(systemName: "globe")! to UIImage(named:"globe")! .

Comment: Apple added SF Symbols to xCode so for sure globe exists and its a system icon.